# CSS image grid without using object-fit: cover

Tags: html, css, image, grid, responsive

Basically trying to acheive what Adobe Stock and Shutterstock have which is a horizontal masonry grid without changing image aspect ratios with object fit or any other stretching.

Every solution uses object-fit: cover which means the images are cropped.

My images are coming from an API where they all are different sizes.

The closest I have is:

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div class='image'>
        <img src='' alt=''>
    </div>

    <div class='image'>
        <img src='' alt=''>
    </div>

    <div class='image'>
        <img src='' alt=''>
    </div>
</div
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 2px;
    max-height: 300px;
}

img {
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

But this gives some mild stretching on images.

The idea would be to have the row take up any amount of vertical space to make the images fit in that row while maintaining their respective aspect ratios.

Comment: Do you mean you want the row to take up any amount of vertical space or would a max-height, as you have in your code already, be what you need?

Comment: I think the best solution would be any amount of vertical space up to a limit. But I figured there cannot be a limit if a specific image needs a lot of vertical space to make sure everything else lines up.

Answer (score 0):

I think object-fit contain may help here. However, exactly whether it looks 'best' with all images the same height, or going up to a maximum height for instance depends on what effect is ultimately wanted.

Here's a snippet in which each img is given a maximum height (300px is chosen simply because that was in the question's code, it could of course be say 30vh or...). It would also be possible to give each img a height of 300px to have them lined up.

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 2px;
    height: 300px;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

img {
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div class='image'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>

    <div class='image'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/400x200.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>

    <div class='image'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/200x400.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>
    <div class='image'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/600x300.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>
    <div class='image'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/1024x768.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>
    <div class='image'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>
</div>
```